# Why do newspapers use the terms "women voters" and "women candidates"?

Tags: grammatical-gender, politics, political-correctness

I've noticed that when discussing political demographics or candidates, many reporters use the phrases "women voters" and "women candidates".  This feels horribly awkward grammatically.  It's hard to imagine referring to male voters or candidates as "men voters" or "men candidates".  Is there a reason that the word women is more commonly used than female in these situations?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I know what you're talking about, but a little context would be good.

Comment: Here is a sentence from an article I read earlier today:

"With women voters in particular, Lott said, 'Newt certainly has problems in that area.'"

Comment: I agree that it is a bit ugly, but it is mainly a matter of style. As Barrie says, noun adjectives can be appropriate in some contexts, though they are sometimes overused.

Comment: *[Woman](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/woman)* as an adjective is in the dictionary; perhaps the adjective *women* is an eggcorn.  So its use isn't grammatically awkward, since it's popular and recognized in the dictionary, but it's still an interesting question why *woman* is popularly used as an adjective when *man* isn't (at least only very informally).

Comment: In the example provided above, *women* is stated explicitly because in the example given, the voters' sex matters. Very often candidates and voters are not distinguished because, for present purposes, their sex does not matter. *Men voters* is very commonly used as well when the *maleness* of the voters is a distinguishing feature for the purpose at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing grammatically awkward about it. Nouns are often used to modify other nouns. The reason 'women' is used rather than 'female' is a general cultural one rather than a specific linguistic one. I'd speculate that 'female' may sound too impersonal, and possibly inhuman, to some ears.

Comment: I agree that there's nothing grammatically *incorrect* about it, but hearing `men voters` grates on my ears; in fact [google ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=male+voters%2C+men+vorters&year_start=1893&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows a flat 0.000% for `men voters`

Comment: @Jim: you were looking for men vorters with an extra r.   Try [this instead](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=women+voters%2Cfemale+voters%2Cmen+voters%2Cmale+voters&year_start=1893&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: Oops!  Good catch- but even corrected it is corroborating.